# Using truth tables to determine whether (a ∧ ¬b) ↔ (a ∧ ¬c) is logically equivalent to b ↔ c

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I've solved the truth table, but I can't tell if they're logically equivalent as I'm not sure whether I am meant to stop at line 4 or consider the whole column.

[Truth Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AyYUL.jpg)
So I have:

(a ∧ ¬b) ↔ (a ∧ ¬c):
T F F T T T T T

b ↔ c:
T F F T T F F T

The first 4 lines of each are logically equivalent, but the last 4 are different. Do I ignore the last 4 or consider the whole 8 lines of each column?

Cheers

Comment: Why do you think that possibly only a part of the truth table is relevant?

Comment: @drhab I thought maybe because there are only 2 variables considered it would only go down 4 times, but it's probably a very silly question.

Comment: @Jeremy: With the same reasoning, would you conclude that $a\land b$ is equivalent to $b$?

Comment: @HenningMakholm Wow, that made me realise how terrible of a question this is. Sorry, thanks.

Comment: Glad to help. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not. Take $b=1$ and $c=0$. Then $b\Leftrightarrow c$ is $0$ (false), while $(a\wedge \neg b) \Leftrightarrow (a\wedge \neg c)$ with $a=0$ is $1$ (true), as both sides are $0$.